# Is there a way to make the header and footer of an html with css show always even if the webpage is scrollable ? (without javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

All I want is to make the header stick at the top & the footer stick at the bottom
centerized for all display aspect ratios
and be visible in a scrollable webpage
because it will be one big site
without other pages

i.e

1. an image at the top
2. about us under it
3. links of the site
4. an image slider
   e.t.c

without depending on Javascript

Thank you in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="index_dark.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="home_dark.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>IndiePump</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Starting with the Header of the Site-->
    <header class="main-header">
      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">
        <img src="logo_header.png">
        <div class="brand-logo-name">IndiePump</div>
      </a>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="login_dark.html">Join Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="moon-button"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- Setting Up the Footer-Bar of the Site-->
    <footer class="main-footer">
      <nav class="footer-container">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="contact-link">
              <img src="social_icons/dark/email.png"</img>
              Contact Us
            </a>
          </li>
          <div class="copyright-container">
            <img src="social_icons/dark/copyright.png"></img>
            <p>2021</p>
          </div>
          <div class="dev-container">
            <img src="social_icons/dark/developed.png"></img>
            <p>Ver 1.0</p>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <nav class="footer-container">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="facebook-link">
                <img src="social_icons/dark/facebook.png"></img>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="twitter-link">
                <img src="social_icons/dark/twitter.png"></img>
              </a>
            </li>
            <!--<li>
              <a href="#" class="instagram-link">
                <img scr="social_icons/dark/instagram.jpg"></img>
              </a>
            </li>-->
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="discord-link">
                <img src="social_icons/dark/discord.png"></img>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="messenger-link">
                <img src="social_icons/dark/messenger.png"></img>
              </a>
            </li>

      </nav>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>



*/ 
The CSS Part
/*
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700");

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display; grid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1a1b20;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-header {
  height: 110px
}

.brand-logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.brand-logo-name {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.moon-button {
  background-image: url(moon.png);
  background-color: #1a1b20;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
}

.moon-button:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.main-footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 65px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-container ul{
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.contact-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.contact-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.copyright-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.copyright-container:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.dev-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.dev-container:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.facebook-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.facebook-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.twitter-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.twitter-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.discord-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.discord-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.discord-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.discord-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.messenger-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.messenger-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: make their position fixed...for header top:0 and for footer bottom:0;

Comment: An image tag is a self closing tag. `</img>` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: fixed` for your `header` and `footer`

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,700");
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display;
  grid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1a1b20;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-header {
  height: 110px
}

.brand-logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.brand-logo-name {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.moon-button {
  background-image: url(moon.png);
  background-color: #1a1b20;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
}

.moon-button:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.main-footer {
  display: flex;
  height: 65px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-container {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-container ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.contact-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.contact-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.copyright-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.copyright-container:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.dev-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.dev-container:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.facebook-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.facebook-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.twitter-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.twitter-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.discord-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.discord-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.discord-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.discord-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.messenger-link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 0;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  color: gold;
  outline: none;
}

.messenger-link:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/* added */

body {
  color: grey;
  margin: 4em 0;
  height: 300vh;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Starting with the Header of the Site-->
<header class="main-header">
  <a href="/" class="brand-logo">
    <img src="logo_header.png">
    <div class="brand-logo-name">IndiePump</div>
  </a>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="login_dark.html">Join Us</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html" class="moon-button"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<!-- Setting Up the Footer-Bar of the Site-->
<footer class="main-footer">
  <nav class="footer-container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="contact-link">
          <img src="social_icons/dark/email.png"> Contact Us
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="copyright-container">
      <img src="social_icons/dark/copyright.png">
      <p>2021</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dev-container">
      <img src="social_icons/dark/developed.png">
      <p>Ver 1.0</p>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <nav class="footer-container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="facebook-link">
          <img src="social_icons/dark/facebook.png">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="twitter-link">
          <img src="social_icons/dark/twitter.png">
        </a>
      </li>
      <!--<li>
              <a href="#" class="instagram-link">
                <img scr="social_icons/dark/instagram.jpg">
              </a>
            </li>-->
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="discord-link">
          <img src="social_icons/dark/discord.png">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="messenger-link">
          <img src="social_icons/dark/messenger.png">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>

Some text
```

You have quiet a few mistakes in HTML, like `<img>` doesn't need `</img>`, and missing `</ul>` tags.

Comment: Your right mr.fumble fingers (mistake by speed)

Comment: What about scaling ?

Comment: In another site when I used fixed positions and switched to another screen the site was awful

Comment: I don't see any problem with scaling

Comment: How can I pm you ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using JavaScript, you should include the header and footer codes in all pages.

As vanowm answered, positioning the header to fixed is a thing mostly seen in webpages, and when you manually include the html code for header in whatever page you want then there won't be such issues.

One thing I would suggest is to have one more sticky division with header when you want your header to be fixed on top of your site.

```
<!-- Starting with the Header of the Site-->
<header class="main-header">
  <a href="/" class="brand-logo">
    <img src="logo_header.png">
    <div class="brand-logo-name">IndiePump</div>
  </a>
  <nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="login_dark.html">Join Us</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html" class="moon-button"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="stickydiv" style="margin-bottum:'The height of the header' "></div>
```

If you really don't want to use javascript you can use php too in this case.

```
<?php include "header.html";?>

//Your page design here....

<?php include "footer.html";?>
```

This helps you to include header and footer in pages you want with simple line of code.

If you change you wish to use Javascript in future you can do it as...

```
    <div id ="header"> </div>
    
    //Your page here...
    
    <div id= "footer"> </div>
    <script>
    
    //Javascript
    
          function load_home(){
                document.getElementById("header").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="header.html" ></object>';
                document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="footer.html" ></object>';
      }
    
    //Jquery
    
    $('#header').load("header.html");
    $('#footer').load("footer.html");
    </script>
```